Add totals in likert plot in ggplot2 in R
I have this data frame in R called df :
df
# A tibble: 5 × 7
  var       n `Very \n Dissatisfied` Dissatisfied Neutral Satisfied `Very \n Satisfied`
  <chr> <int>                  <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>               <dbl>
1 A       106                   18.9         14.5    23.0      22.0                21.7
2 B       106                   19.2         16.0    25.5      18.9                20.4
3 C        87                   22.2         25.3    15.7      17.2                19.5
4 D       102                   19.0         19.0    21.2      22.9                18.0
5 E        99                   22.2         20.5    20.9      17.5                18.9




from this data frame I have create two plots, one likert plot and one bar plot :

df_long <- df %>%
  select(-n)%>%
  pivot_longer(!var, names_to = "Likert", values_to = "Percentage")
# Likert plot
likert_plot <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = var, y = Percentage, fill = Likert)) +
  geom_col(position = position_likert(reverse = FALSE)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = label_percent_abs(hide_below = .01, accuracy = 1)(Percentage),
      color = after_scale(hex_bw(.data$fill))
    ),
    position = position_likert(vjust = 0.5, reverse = FALSE),
    size = 3.5
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(
    title = "Likert Responses by Category",
    x = "Category",
    y = "Percentage",
    fill = "Likert Scale"
  ) +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal()+scale_fill_manual(values = custom_colors) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL)

# Horizontal bar plot
bar_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = n, y = var)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightgrey") +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      label = label_number_abs(hide_below = .05, accuracy = 2)(n)
    ),
    size = 3.5,
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
    hjust = 1,
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0,
    color = "black"
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = \(x) gsub("\\..*$", "", x)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = label_percent_abs(),
    expand = c(0, .15)
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank()  # Hides x-axis numbers
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL)

# Print plots

(likert_plot) +(bar_plot)+
  plot_layout(
   width = c(4,1)
  ) &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")


that look like this :

I want :

the percentages inside each bar level to round them to 0 decimal places
make them bold
add the totals at right and left .(ie totals at left is the sum of very dissatisfied and satisfied and the totals at right the sum of satisfied and ver satisfied)

How can I achieve these in R ?
Data
dput(df)
structure(list(var = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), n = c(106L, 
106L, 87L, 102L, 99L), `Very 
 Dissatisfied` = c(18.8679245283019, 
19.1823899371069, 22.2222222222222, 18.9542483660131, 22.2222222222222
), Dissatisfied = c(14.4654088050314, 16.0377358490566, 25.2873563218391, 
18.9542483660131, 20.5387205387205), Neutral = c(22.9559748427673, 
25.4716981132075, 15.7088122605364, 21.2418300653595, 20.8754208754209
), Satisfied = c(22.0125786163522, 18.8679245283019, 17.2413793103448, 
22.8758169934641, 17.5084175084175), `Very 
 Satisfied` = c(21.6981132075472, 
20.440251572327, 19.5402298850575, 17.9738562091503, 18.8552188552189
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))



To achieve your desired result set the scale= parameter in label_percent_abs to 1 to avoid that the proportions are multiplied by the default 100. To have bold labels use fontface="bold" in geom_text. Finally, to get the labels you can use a separate dataframe where you compute the totals (similar to what I have done in answers on your former questions), then use a second geom_text/label:
df <- data.frame(
  var = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  n = c(106, 106, 87, 102, 99),
  `Very \n Dissatisfied` = c(18.9, 19.2, 22.2, 19.0, 22.2),
  Dissatisfied = c(14.5, 16.0, 25.3, 19.0, 20.5),
  Neutral = c(23.0, 25.5, 15.7, 21.2, 20.9),
  Satisfied = c(22.0, 18.9, 17.2, 22.9, 17.5),
  `Very \n Satisfied` = c(21.7, 20.4, 19.5, 18.0, 18.9),
  check.names = FALSE
)

library(tidyverse)
library(ggstats)
library(patchwork)

levels <- names(df)[-c(1:2)]
df_long <- df %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  pivot_longer(!var, names_to = "Likert", values_to = "Percentage") |>
  mutate(Likert = factor(Likert, levels))

custom_colors <- c(
  "#D91828", "#D98989", "#71B1D9", "#71F26D", "#17A621"
)
names(custom_colors) <- levels

df_tot <- df_long |>
  summarise(
    prop_lower = sum(Percentage[Likert %in% levels[1:2]]),
    prop_higher = sum(Percentage[Likert %in% levels[4:5]]),
    .by = var
  ) |>
  pivot_longer(-var,
    names_prefix = "prop_",
    values_to = "Percentage",
    names_to = "where"
  )

# Likert plot
likert_plot <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Percentage, y = var, fill = Likert)) +
  geom_col(position = position_likert(reverse = FALSE)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = label_percent_abs(hide_below = .01, accuracy = 1, scale = 1)(Percentage),
      color = after_scale(hex_bw(fill))
    ),
    position = position_likert(vjust = 0.5, reverse = FALSE),
    size = 3.5,
    fontface = "bold"
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = df_tot,
    aes(
      label = label_percent_abs(hide_below = .01, accuracy = 1, scale = 1)(Percentage),
      x = ifelse(where == "lower", -.6, .6),
      fill = NULL
    ),
    size = 3.5,
    fontface = "bold",
    label.size = 0,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = label_percent_abs()
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Likert Responses by Category",
    x = "Category",
    y = "Percentage",
    fill = "Likert Scale"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = custom_colors) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")

# Horizontal bar plot
bar_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = n, y = var)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightgrey") +
  geom_label(
    aes(
      label = label_number_abs(hide_below = .05, accuracy = 2)(n)
    ),
    size = 3.5,
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
    hjust = 1,
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0,
    color = "black"
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = \(x) gsub("\\..*$", "", x)) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = label_percent_abs(),
    expand = c(0, .15)
  ) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank() # Hides x-axis numbers
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL)

# Print plots

(likert_plot) + (bar_plot) +
  plot_layout(
    width = c(4, 1)
  ) &
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")



can we force the color of the text inside each bar level to be black? Because the red (very dissatified level) is white.

Sure. Simply drop the color = after_scale(hex_bw(fill)) you added in the geom_text.

thank you very much for your clear answer. One last question:if i want to sort (both plots) based on the  prop_lower or prop_higher what adjustments i have to do in tour answer code?

First, get the order using e.g. var_ordered <- levels(   with(df_tot, reorder(     var, ifelse(where == "lower", Percentage, NA),     na.rm = TRUE   )) ) to order by prop_lower. Then add/use scale_y_discrete(limits = var_ordered) to both plots.

i am speechless Stefan. Thank you very much.

last last last question:if i want the first n categories ?
